# Curl error : name lookup timed out

Tags: magento-1.9, error, rest-api

I'm working on a custom shipping method linked with an external REST API.

When the seller submits a shipment, an API call is done in order to reserve a shipping course for our carriers.

The problem is that the cURL call fails with this error:

> cURL Error: name lookup timed out

I tried something like this :

```
$curlPostData = $bookCourseRequest; // an object containing the data sent to the API
$curlPostData = json_encode($curlPostData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

$curlQuery = curl_init( //we will assume that the URL is correct );
curl_setopt($curlQuery, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curlQuery, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPostData);
$header = array("content-type: application/json");
curl_setopt($curlQuery, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlQuery, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curlQuery, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
$curlAnswer = curl_exec($curlQuery);
if (!$curlAnswer)
    mage::log("cURL Error: " . curl_error($curlQuery));
else
    $answer = json_decode($curlAnswer);
curl_close($curlQuery);
```

Fun fact: this code works well on Magento 2 and on an PHP file unlinked with Magento. With Magento 1.9, there is a timeout error.

I tried the varian way but no luck: still the same error.

Does someone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code

**Get**:-

```
$client_account_details = new Zend_Http_Client('https://domain.com/');
        $client_account_details->setHeaders('X-Auth-Token','token' );
        $client_account_details->setHeaders('Content-Type', 'application/json');  
        $client_account_details->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET);  
        $account_details_result=$client_account_details->request()->getRawBody();
```

**Post** :-

```
$request_json = json_encode($response_array);
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client();   
    $client->setUri('https://domain.com/'); 
    $client->setHeaders('X-Auth-Token','token' );
    $client->setHeaders(Zend_Http_Client::CONTENT_TYPE, 'application/json'); 
    $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);   
    $client->setRawData($request_json);   
    $response = $client->request()->getBody();
```